# Search with "Hash sign" in Solr

Tags: java, php, mysql, solr

I am new to Solr and facing problems while optimizing the search in solr.
When i search for "C4902AN#140", it displays results with "140" first and result with ""C4902AN#140" is appearing later.i.e. after results containing "140".But I want result with "C4902AN#140" before results having "140".

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what's your analysis?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to check with tokenizer you used for field type definition in schema file.

if the field type has solr.standardTokenizer it will remove # character.

> OR

you should consider boosting the document which has"C4902AN#140"

you can use elevate.xml file in config folder and just mention which document to appear first in the resultset for specific searchTerm string.

Comment: It seems that "#" does not work in elevate.xml file.Only simple  text works like "foo bar".Any idea for tokenizer? Thanks for your help

Comment: In schema file change solr.StandardTokenizerFactory to solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory for that field Type definition(field which stores values "C4902AN#140")

Answer (score 0):

The Analyzer which you are using for this should be using KeyWordTokenizerFactory so that your whole word does not get Tokenized , but only a single token , i.e the word itself is generated .